# Am I using getCreatedTime() the right way?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

This is my code:

```
$node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
$created_time = $node->getCreatedTime();
```

Drush watchdog shows the following error:

> Error: Call to a member function getCreatedTime() on null in Drupal...

What is the problem?

Comment: You get noting on the first line, therefore you can not call the function `getCreatedTime()`.

Comment: `$node` is null. The first line does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to get current node like this:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

But it not always return node object. For example, if you on the views page, it will returns null. So, you must check returned value:

```
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  $created_time = $node->getCreatedTime();
}
```